# What are the limits of vert.x handler<> and why futur is used instead?

Tags: java, webserver, reactive-programming, vert.x

What are the limits of vert.x handler<> and why futur is used instead !

What is the difference between the handler interface and futur ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vert.x, a `Handler` is an asynchronous callback function. The only "limitation" it has is that it shouldn't contain blocking code.

A `Future` is a result of an asynchronous function.

`Future` is not used instead of `Handler`. You can have a handler that doesn't return a future, or you can have a Future that is not returned by a handler.